# How i get the row from mysql database through where column value

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get rows value from two tables i.e.

- table1 `sale(id,name invoiceno,saleprice,total)` and
- table2: `invoice(id,invoiceno,saledisc,disctotal)`

I want the rows from both tables where `invoiceno` is common.

Anyone's co-operation is  highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use join to select value from 2 tbl

```
$sq="SELECT s.*, i.*
FROM sale s
INNER JOIN invoice i
ON s.invoiceno=i.invoiceno";
```

Comment: The invoiceno is in the from of $invoiceno=10001

Comment: then collect in variable and use in query

Comment: I think this will clear you $sq="SELECT s.*, i.*
FROM sale s
INNER JOIN invoice i
ON s.$invoiceno=i.$invoiceno";

Comment: What problem u r facing ?

Comment: Query Like this is not working. $invoiceno=10001 is already a table value. how i show the row against this value

Comment: The Query I am using is.

Comment: "select sale.id,sale.invoiceno,sale.dattime,sale.tim,sale.name,sale.quantity,sale.purchasePrice,sale.salePrice,sale.total,sale.itemdiscount,sale.totalafterdisc,invoice.flatdisc,invoice.addcharges,invoice.saledisc,invoice.totalamount from sale INNER JOIN invoice on invoice.$invoiceno=sale.$invoiceno ";

Comment: var_dump u r query and run in db .to ckeck what error u r getting

Comment: include('connection.php');
    $dat= $_POST['rngstrt'];
    $invoiceno= $_POST['rngstrt1'];
    $query2="select sale.id,sale.invoiceno,sale.dattime,sale.tim,sale.name,sale.quantity,sale.purchasePrice,sale.salePrice,sale.total,sale.itemdiscount,sale.totalafterdisc,invoice.flatdisc,invoice.addcharges,invoice.saledisc,invoice.totalamount from sale INNER JOIN invoice on invoice.$invoiceno=sale.$invoiceno ";
    $result=mysql_query($query2);

Comment: var_dump($query2);and run in sql

Comment: Error Not displaying on the page

Comment: if you  var_dump($query2); you will get complete query with variable values ,then copy that query and run it in sql tab of mysql .you will come to know what is wrong

Comment: Error Coming: Invalid Query: Query was empty

Comment: don't copy  query with quotes

Answer (score 0):

I'll help you with this one, although it is so basic you better consider an online SQL course before asking any further questions.

```
SELECT * FROM SALE INNER JOIN INVOICE ON sale.invoiceNo = invoice.invoiceNo
```